# Сравнение чисел без условного оператора

Tags: python

[image: вот сама задача]

Тут подвох в чем: нельзя использовать `if`, `max`, `min`, и знаки сравнения.

Comment: На будущее- не ленитесь перевести вопрос в текстовый вид. и было бы неплохо, если бы вы указывали свои попытки решения.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
m = 2; n = 8

print( int(not '-' in str(m - n)) )
```

Comment: отличный вариант - все остальные как-то забыли про строки)

Comment: спасибо большое, выручили

Answer (score 8):

Забавная задача, в принципе у меня получилось то же самое сравнение, но закамуфлированное, `range` вроде не запрещён:

```
def greater(m, n, k=10**6):
    return (m - n) in range(k)

assert greater(1, 1) == 1
assert greater(4, 3) == 1
assert greater(2, 8) == 0

print(int(greater(1, 1)))
print(int(greater(4, 3)))
print(int(greater(2, 8)))
```

Вывод:

```
1
1
0
```

P.S. `range` в `Python 3` - специальный объект, фактически хранящий только свои параметры и умеющий моментально проверять вхождение числа в свой диапазон.

Answer (score 7):

**Вариант 1:** Один из возможных вариантов - вызвать функцию, выкидывающую исключение при отрицательном аргументе (например логарифм) и перехватить исключение:

```
from math import log

m,n = 1,2

try:
    _ = log(m - n + 1e-8)
    print(1)
except ValueError:
    print(0)
```

---

**Вариант 2:** можно воспользоваться функцией [math.copysign()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/math.html#math.copysign):

```
from math import copysign

print(int(copysign(1, m-n)))
```

Если `m < n` напечатается `-1`, что соответствует условиям задачи (`"любое другое число"`).

---

**Вариант 3:**  можно округлить значение [сигмоиды](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%B8%D0%B3%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B8%D0%B4%D0%B0) до целого числа:

```
import math

def sigmoid(x, eps=1e-8):
    return 1 / (1 + math.exp(-x)) + eps
```

тесты:

```
In [211]: print(round(sigmoid(-2)))
0

In [212]: print(round(sigmoid(1)))
1

In [213]: print(round(sigmoid(0)))
1
```

Comment: На 1,1 не сработает )  Логарифм от нуля тоже упадёт ;)

Comment: @CrazyElf, точно, спасибо! Сейчас подумаю... Пока сделал костыль в виде эпсилон

Comment: Можно ведь просто 1 добавить к m

Comment: @КириллМалышев, да можно и единицу, но "эпсилон" мне почему-то нравится больше)

Comment: Ох уж этот волшебный эпсилон ))

Answer (score 5):

Можно так, но оно ищет максимум, что не совсем то, что вам нужно:

```py
from sys import getsizeof as sizeof

CHAR_BIT = 8

def flip(bit):
    return 1^bit

def sign(a):
    return flip((a >> (sizeof(int)*CHAR_BIT-1)) & 0x1)
    
def getMax(a, b):
    k = sign(a - b)
    q = flip(k)
    return a*k + b*q
```

UPD:
А вот это уже то, что вам нужно

```py
from sys import getsizeof as sizeof

CHAR_BIT = 8

def ge(a, b):
    return 1^(((a-b) >> (sizeof(int)*CHAR_BIT-1)) & 0x1)

print(ge(2, 2))
```

Comment: Ну, проверять старший (знаковый) бит идея логичная, но реализация её простой не будет, так я и знал )

Answer (score 4):

Забавно, что никто не воспользовался заданным в условии ограничением:

> по модулю не превосходящие 10^6

Зная максимальное значение можно наложить маску с единицами во всех разрядах на разность `n - m` оператором `|` (*побитовое или*). В случае отрицательного значения *знаковый бит* выявляется сам-собой как -1, а все положителные значения заменяются значением маски. Для включения условия равенства добавляем смещение на единицу.

```
def cmp(m, n):
    return -((n - m - 1) | 0xffffff)
```